# How can I assign a value to a new column to show that a group of rows are related?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need some help on `SQL Server T-SQL` problem.

I've a `T-SQL` table that has an `id field (PK)`, a second column with a list of `Ids` and a third column with another list of `Ids`.  I am trying to match up all the `Ids` from the second column to the third column and all those that appear in the third column to the second column and assign a new column with a value that groups all the related ids together.

```
Sample Table
----------
ID  | Ref1  | Ref2
1   |  41   | 42    |
2   |  42   | 41    |
3   |  42   | 43    |
4   |  42   | 41    |
5   |  42   | 43    |
6   |  43   | 42    |
7   |  43   | 44    |
8   |  43   | 42    |
9   |  44   | 43    |
10  |  53   | 54    |
11  |  54   | 53    |
11  |  54   | 55    |
11  |  55   | 54    |
11  |  56   | 57    |
11  |  57   | 56    |
```

Those values that appear in `Ref2` that are also in `Ref1` and those that are in `Ref1` that are also in `Ref2` should be grouped together and assigned a value so I know that they are all of the same order.  For example `Ref1` value 41 has a `Ref2` value 42 so they are grouped, all other values that appear in `Ref1` or `Ref2` for 42 should also be grouped together with 41 and they are assigned as 1 (or any value) in the new column.  I then know that values 41, 42, 43 and 44 are all from the same order.

```
Desired Results
----------
ID  | Ref1  | Ref2  |  New Column 
1   |  41   | 42    |  1
2   |  42   | 41    |  1
3   |  42   | 43    |  1
4   |  42   | 41    |  1
5   |  42   | 43    |  1
6   |  43   | 42    |  1
7   |  43   | 44    |  1
8   |  43   | 42    |  1
9   |  44   | 43    |  1
10  |  53   | 54    |  2
11  |  54   | 53    |  2
11  |  54   | 55    |  2
11  |  55   | 54    |  2
11  |  56   | 57    |  3
11  |  57   | 56    |  3
```

I've tried to `row_number` and `Rank` but I can't get the related values to be included in the new column.

Answer (score 0):

This produces the desired result as you wanted above, although it is calculating the group instead of deriving it in a select statement.  Hope it helps you

```
declare @t table (id int, ref1 int, ref2 int, groupid int)
insert into @t (id, ref1, ref2) values (1,41,42),(2,42,41),(3,42,43),(4,42,41),(5,42,43),(6,43,42),(7,43,44),(8,43,42),(9,44,43),(10,53,54),(11,54,53),(11,54,55),(11,55,54),(11,56,57),(11,57,56)

declare @grpid int = 1
update top (1) @t set groupid = @grpid --just set the first record to the first group id

while exists (select * from @t where groupid is null) 
begin
    update @t set groupid = @grpid 
    where groupid is null 
    and (
        ref1 in (select ref2 from @t where groupid = @grpid) 
        or
        ref2 in (select ref1 from @t where groupid = @grpid) 
        )

    if @@ROWCOUNT = 0 --nothing updated by the above update statement so time to move on to new group id
    begin --set next unassigned records to a new group 
        set @grpid = @grpid + 1 
        update top (1) @t set groupid = @grpid where groupid is null
    end
end

select * from @t
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great and does what I need.  I was trying to avoid any temporary tables but it does what I need.  Just going to slot it into my report.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

That was fun, kind of a *gaps and islands* issue... ;-)

Try this (I added some more cases at the end)

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(id INT, ref1 INT, ref2 INT)
INSERT INTO @t (id, ref1, ref2) VALUES
(1,41,42),(2,42,41),(3,42,43),(4,42,41),(5,42,43),(6,43,42),(7,43,44),(8,43,42),(9,44,43),(10,53,54),(11,54,53),(11,54,55),(11,55,54),(11,56,57),(11,57,56),(12,43,46),(12,45,43);



WITH Sorted AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY LowRef,HighRef) AS RowNumber
             ,t.id,t.ref1 AS OrigRef1,t.ref2 AS OrigRef2
             ,LowRef AS ref1
             ,HighRef AS ref2
    FROM @t t
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT CASE WHEN t.ref1<t.ref2 THEN t.ref1 ELSE t.ref2 END
                      ,CASE WHEN t.ref1>t.ref2 THEN t.ref1 ELSE t.ref2 END) A(LowRef,HighRef)
)
,recCTE AS
(
    SELECT t.RowNumber,t.id,t.OrigRef1,t.OrigRef2,ref1 AS LowBound,ref2 AS HighBound, 1 AS GroupId 
    FROM Sorted t
    WHERE t.RowNumber=1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT t.RowNumber,t.id,t.OrigRef1,t.OrigRef2
          ,CASE WHEN WithinGroup=1 THEN CASE WHEN r.LowBound<t.ref1 THEN r.LowBound ELSE t.ref1 END ELSE t.ref1 END
          ,CASE WHEN WithinGroup=1 THEN CASE WHEN r.HighBound>t.ref2 THEN r.HighBound ELSE t.ref2 END ELSE t.ref2 END
          ,CASE WHEN WithinGroup=1 THEN r.GroupId ELSE r.GroupId+1 END 
    FROM Sorted t
    INNER JOIN recCTE r ON t.RowNumber=r.RowNumber+1
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT CASE WHEN t.ref1 BETWEEN r.LowBound AND r.HighBound OR t.ref2 BETWEEN r.LowBound AND r.HighBound THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) A(WithinGroup)
)

SELECT t.RowNumber
      ,t.id
      ,t.OrigRef1
      ,t.OrigRef2
      ,MIN(t.LowBound) OVER(PARTITION BY t.GroupId) AS LowBound
      ,MAX(t.HighBound) OVER(PARTITION BY t.GroupId) AS HighBound
      ,t.GroupId
FROM recCTE t;
```

The result

```
+-----------+----+----------+----------+----------+-----------+---------+
| RowNumber | id | OrigRef1 | OrigRef2 | LowBound | HighBound | GroupId |
+-----------+----+----------+----------+----------+-----------+---------+
| 1         | 4  | 42       | 41       | 41       | 46        | 1       |
+-----------+----+----------+----------+----------+-----------+---------+
| 2         | 1  | 41       | 42       | 41       | 46        | 1       |
+-----------+----+----------+----------+----------+-----------+---------+
| 3         | 2  | 42       | 41       | 41       | 46        | 1       |
+-----------+----+----------+----------+----------+-----------+---------+
| 4         | 3  | 42       | 43       | 41       | 46        | 1       |
+-----------+----+----------+----------+----------+-----------+---------+
| 5         | 5  | 42       | 43       | 41       | 46        | 1       |
+-----------+----+----------+----------+----------+-----------+---------+
| 6         | 6  | 43       | 42       | 41       | 46        | 1       |
+-----------+----+----------+----------+----------+-----------+---------+
| 7         | 8  | 43       | 42       | 41       | 46        | 1       |
+-----------+----+----------+----------+----------+-----------+---------+
| 8         | 9  | 44       | 43       | 41       | 46        | 1       |
+-----------+----+----------+----------+----------+-----------+---------+
| 9         | 7  | 43       | 44       | 41       | 46        | 1       |
+-----------+----+----------+----------+----------+-----------+---------+
| 10        | 12 | 45       | 43       | 41       | 46        | 1       |
+-----------+----+----------+----------+----------+-----------+---------+
| 11        | 12 | 43       | 46       | 41       | 46        | 1       |
+-----------+----+----------+----------+----------+-----------+---------+
| 12        | 10 | 53       | 54       | 53       | 55        | 2       |
+-----------+----+----------+----------+----------+-----------+---------+
| 13        | 11 | 54       | 53       | 53       | 55        | 2       |
+-----------+----+----------+----------+----------+-----------+---------+
| 14        | 11 | 54       | 55       | 53       | 55        | 2       |
+-----------+----+----------+----------+----------+-----------+---------+
| 15        | 11 | 55       | 54       | 53       | 55        | 2       |
+-----------+----+----------+----------+----------+-----------+---------+
| 16        | 11 | 56       | 57       | 56       | 57        | 3       |
+-----------+----+----------+----------+----------+-----------+---------+
| 17        | 11 | 57       | 56       | 56       | 57        | 3       |
+-----------+----+----------+----------+----------+-----------+---------+
```

### The idea in short

The first CTE sanitizes your data in the way, that `ref1` is not bigger than `ref2` and a unique row-id is added.

Now we go into recursion. We start with the row *Number 1* and travers down by joining on "`RowNumber==RowNumber+1`". Thus running iteratively through the set *row-by-row* we can check, if the current row is within the current intervall and - if not - start a new intervall.

The final `SELECT` will return the Groups with their boundaries and a group-id.

Comment: that's brilliant, thank you.  I'm going to have a play with both answer and might be able to do more with the output than I originally thought.